# Twilio IP Messaging user not found

Tags: rest, twilio, messaging

I'm trying to add a users identity to a channel using the REST API using instructions here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/members#action-create

I'm posting to the `/Channels/channelId/Members` endpoint - I'm certain my request is structured correctly.

I get an error back from Twilio IP Messaging saying:

```
{"code": 50200, "message": "User not found", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/50200", "status": 400}
```

My understanding was that we can provide our own identity when we want to add someone to a Channel. How can I 'register' the user (with an email) before adding them to the Channel?

EDIT - The code:

```
var _getRequestBaseUrl = function() {
  return 'https://' +
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID + ':' +
    process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN + '@' +
    TWILIO_BASE + 'Services/' +
    process.env.TWILIO_IPM_SERVICE_SID + '/';
};

var addMemberToChannel = function(memberIdentity, channelId) {                                          
  var options = {
    url: _getRequestBaseUrl() + 'Channels/' + channelId + '/Members',                              
    method: 'POST',                                                                                
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                         
    },
    form: {
      Identity: memberIdentity,                                                                    
    },
  };                                                                                           
  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
       // Getting the error here
    }
    // do stuff with response.
  });
};                                                             
addMemberToChannel('test1@example.com', <validChannelId>);
```

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to make the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to add a user to be a member of a channel, you do indeed need to register them first. Check out the documentation for [creating a user in IP Messaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/users#action-create).

With your code you'd need a function like:

```
var createUser = function(memberIdentity) {
  var options = {
    url: _getRequestBaseUrl() + 'Users',
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    form: {
      Identity: memberIdentity,            
    }
  };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
       // User couldn't be created
    }
    // do stuff with user.
  });
}
```

Could I also suggest you take a look at the [Twilio helper library for Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install). It handles the creation of URLs like you're doing for you. The code looks cleaner too, you can create a user with the helper library like this:

```
var accountSid = 'ACCOUNT_SID';
var authToken = 'AUTH_TOKEN';
var IpMessagingClient = require('twilio').IpMessagingClient;

var client = new IpMessagingClient(accountSid, authToken);
var service = client.services('SERVICE_SID');

service.users.create({
    identity: 'IDENTITY'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Definitely helps. I did try using the twilio client - (npm twilio@3.0.0-rc.2) - but it doesn't have an object called IpMessagingClient.

Comment: Downgrade that to twilio@2.9.0 and you should find it matches the documentation again. The 3.0.0 series is in pre-release and the docs haven't caught up yet.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why is twilio documentation lagging as compared to the released versions? We too are enthusiasts to use twilio library for Call/SMS/IP Messg and Video Conversations, However we are unable to make any progress with sending invites to the users by remote notifications using Twilio iOS SDK. The documentation is very poor on the Remote notifications section. It does tell me how to setup remote notification. However, even after following the step by step guidelines, we are unable to receive any notifications from the twilio servers. The didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate just doesn't fire!!!

Comment: Hi @DeepakBadiger, sorry you are having trouble with this. IP Messaging is still in beta at the moment, so things like documentation may not be quite as up to date as you might hope. The comment section of an SO answer is probably not the best place to discuss this though. Do you want to email me at philnash@twilio.com and describe what's going on in detail? Hopefully I can either help or direct your questions to the right person in Twilio.

Comment: Hi Philnash, Thanks for the quick turnaround. Yes, i would send you the details on a separate thread in your mailbox. Thanks for helping out in advance.